# Rails routing error. Application doesn't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, github

Heyy guys, please help me. I am from 4 days on **dreamhost** setting up **rails**. Finally rails has started working but application is not running. I have just deployed a demo app with only one model Products and the page doesn't opens, it says page doesn't exist. There is written routing error in production log file. I am novice in Rails so could'nt figure out what is going wrong. You can try yourself running [app](http://www.meropati.com/products) **http://meropati.com/products** and see source code of this app with log files on my **[git repository](https://github.com/getaasciesh/TestingRailsOnDreamHost)** **https://github.com/getaasciesh/TestingRailsOnDreamHost**
I will be so thankful to get it's solution.

```
Started GET "/products" for 208.113.229.116 at 2012-07-26 16:05:55 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/products"):
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:516:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:470:in `safe_fork'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
  <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  /home/getaasciesh3/.passenger/standalone/3.0.14-x86_64-ruby1.9.3-linux-gcc4.4.5-1002/support/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Show us the errors in your logs please

Comment: Here I pasted the error message from production log. It is error for one of the many tries. All of them have same error.

Comment: Does your rails website work locally?

Comment: Just a piece of advice. Do not commit your database.yaml to a public repository. There is always sensitive information in files like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not matter, but you've got:

```
gem 'sqlite3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
...
gem 'mysql2'
```

Try removing the first reference to sqlite3 as you don't want it in production.

As I said, it might not make any difference to this particular issue, but it will save you from trouble later on

**Update**

The [dreamhost wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Rails_3) advise against using passenger and rvm, as they don't play too nicely together. Read the section titled "Troubleshooting". They recommend switching to the system installation of ruby.

If you are going to try that, you will probably need to remove the reference to rvm from [environment.rb](https://github.com/getaasciesh/TestingRailsOnDreamHost/blob/master/config/environment.rb)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks I did that, but main problem persists still

Comment: I ran the migration. Nothing happened :/